# how to use python try except output (AWS SDK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-sdk

**Requirement:** Find out unencrypted s3 buckets from AWS account and add tag to it.

**Implemented so far**

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Retrieve the list of existing buckets
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_buckets()


# Find out unencrypted bucket list
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    try:
        enc = s3.get_bucket_encryption(Bucket=bucket["Name"])
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError':
            print('Bucket with no server-side encryption: %s' % (bucket['Name']))
        else:
            print("Bucket with unexpected error: %s, unexpected error: %s" % (bucket['Name'], e))
```

Following line gives me the unencrypted bucketslist:
`print('Bucket with no server-side encryption: %s' % (bucket['Name']))`

**Result:**

```
Bucket with no server-side encryption: xyz1
Bucket with no server-side encryption: xyz2
```

**Need support for following**
I can get the list of unencrypted s3 buckets but not sure how to use the output from `except` python code and utilize unencrypted bucket names to add tag later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a list outside of your try-catch, you can access it later on

E.g.

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

#this is our new list
buckets = []

# Retrieve the list of existing buckets
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_buckets()


# Find out unencrypted bucket list
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    try:
        enc = s3.get_bucket_encryption(Bucket=bucket["Name"])
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError':
            #add the bucket name to our new list
            buckets.append(bucket['Name'])

            print('Bucket with no server-side encryption: %s' % (bucket['Name']))
        else:
            print("Bucket with unexpected error: %s, unexpected error: %s" % (bucket['Name'], e))
    

#now you can use the "buckets" variable and it will contain all the unencrypted buckets
for bucket in buckets:
    print(bucket)
```

Comment: You could also just do `buckets.append(bucket)` if you need any other fields from the object

Comment: Thank you so much Luke for your time and support. I see you have added comments in the code that is really helpful to understand.